# Splitting table into two parts: old data and recent data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table **records** with structure

```
userId
messageId
message
timestamp
```

This table grows pretty large so I want to split it into two 
**records** which will have only data for the last 30 days 
and **records_history** which will have all the data, so most of the queries will hit only **records** table.

What is the best way to achieve this using Oracle? Writing a trigger or something else?

Comment: Partitioning? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm

Comment: Partitioning is a licensed extra to the Enterprise Edition.

Comment: what is the business need behind it? is the table slow? is this a solution looking for a problem?